Example from Real analysis and probability
There is the definition of sequence of sets being $\downarrow \varnothing$.

$A_n:=[n,\infty)$. $A_n = [n,\infty), A_{n+1} = [n+1,\infty)$, so $A_{n+1} \supset A_n$. But $\cap_n A_n = A_n$. On the other side $A_n \neq \varnothing$. So for me it seems like $A_n:=[n,\infty)$ is not $\downarrow \varnothing$. Could you please explain.

I am not very good at math, but I guess this is the case when $n \rightarrow  \infty$. The definition does not say so. Do we suppose, that $n \rightarrow  \infty$ in this definition? We can suppose so because it is countably additive, not finitely. Am I right?

This makes sence, thanks
